# Use Cell Address to Get Cell's Value

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub selectRange()
    Dim A As String
    A = ActiveCell.Address
     MsgBox A
     MsgBox Cells(A)
End Sub
```

When I pass A as a parameter it shows error how should i pass values in parameter for current cell's data.

Comment: Try a `Range` instead

Comment: Thsnk youAs i m new i dont know much about will u please suggest

Comment: Watch this video series: [Excel VBA Introduction](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).  This is relevant: [Part 5 - Ranges, Cells, ActiveCell, Offset](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&t=3123s&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The proper syntax for `Cells()` is:

```
Cells([row number], [column number]).Value
```

To use the cell's address, use `Range()` instead:

```
Range([Address Range]).Value
Range(A).Value 'in your example
```

Comment: I am having the cell's address and I want to pass the address as a parameter to obtain the data on specific cell

Comment: Sub sample()
Dim A As String
    A = ActiveCell.Address
     MsgBox A
     MsgBox Range([A]).Value
End Sub

Comment: @PiyushNarkhede what happens when you try `Range().Value`?

Comment: @PiyushNarkhede don't use brackets around variable. `Range(A).Value`

Comment: i tried above code and it return the data and accepts A as a parameter